# Will external high electric field strength erase flash memory?

Tags: flash

Simple question - given that electric fields are used to program and erase flash memory will placing such a memory in an external high voltage gradient damage them, or damage the bit integrity? I am thinking of fields of around 1 MV/m

Comment: The larger the component the more it will be effected by the external field gradient.  Conductors, (lead frame, wire bonds, perpendicular metallisation) will cause high voltages to appear between them and may result in breakdown of insulation (oxide layers).  A __bare die__ placed flat in an __equipotential__ in that field might be OK with it as it will only see say 20V from top to bottom of a 0.2mm thick die.With wire bonds I would not bet on long term reliability.  All this is just gut feel so not an answer.

Comment: In my experience, it takes a *very* large field strength to flip bits (they are quite susceptible to X-ray incidentally). The weakest part of the link in flash devices is usually the programming voltage charge pump but even that requires a lot of very focused energy to cause damage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash memory uses [floating gate MOSFETs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET) to store a charge.

The amount of charge stored is the actual information.

Let's compare your 1MV/m to the field strength which is used to program such a memory cell.

First question, how thick is the oxide? I found [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/floating-gate) where they mention the oxide thickness to be typically between 15 to 20 nm. Let's use 20 nm.

The programming voltage is often about 10 V, this is very process dependent but let's just use 10 V.

Then we get a field strength in the oxide of: 10 V / 20 nm = 500 MV/m

So that's a **500** times higher field strength than your 1 MV/m

Of course this is a value that ensures reliable programming of the cells, I mean, it could already work at 100 MV/m for example but that could be unreliable.

So in my view, 1 MV/m would by far not be enough to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give a full fledged answer, but found the question interesting enough to do some Google-Fu:

[This document](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~omutlu/pub/flash-read-disturb-errors_dsn15.pdf#page=5) turned up and shows a graph of current density in the tunnel oxide with respect to the electric field strength:

[image: current density vs electric field strength]

So the graph starts at 400 MV/m and the current density seems quite low. I don't know at which point the current density would be high enough to cause defects, but as there is a factor of 400 to the number you are asking about, I'd guess you won't hurt the flash memory cells directly.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many pieces of metal on the memory surface, each being in more or less the state of GROUND. (or +5v) Thus bit-flipping requires generating a high gradient, just 1 or 2 microns away from GROUND. A tough task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it is possible to do that but field required will be around atleast 1 MV/cm (considering 10 nm as oxide thickness and 1V as writting or programmig voltage ), but that does not mean you will need 10 Mega volts or so ! I was working on the same problem and my idea is using sharp metal nails on one side welded to a metal plate and another plate about 5 or 7 cm apart. Electric field near the metal nails will be very high and it will taper off qickly as we move away from nails. But still it will require a very high voltage source (about 1MV !) and rest of the work will be done by electric arc formation.

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose if you form an electric arc and put a flash memory in the middle of it then the flash memory will probably be damaged. But I don't think this is really what the OP was asking about.